# Discord OAuth2: 'Missing "code" in request'

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord

I wrote a Discord OAuth2 vertification code a few months ago and it worked. But now it does not work. Discord responses 'Missing "code" in request'. I looked and my request sends code. How can I solve this?

Code to take `access_token`:

```js
const response = await fetch(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}&redirect_uri=${loginredirect}`,
{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Basic ${creds}`,
  }
});

const json = await response.json();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got the fields you need to call the token endpoint and swap the code for tokens. You need to send the data in the form body though - something like this:

```
const response = await fetch(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token`,
{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Basic ${creds}`,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code,
    redirect_uri: loginredirect,
  }),
});

const json = await response.json();
```

I would also consider using an OAuth security library such as [openid-client](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client), to make more security checks for you, rather than using the raw fetch API.

Comment: It is not working. It is giving error "invalid_grant".